# Useful Wordpress Plugins for a band website

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a website for my band and I have lots experience building websites from scratch, using design patterns, php, mysql, etc, etc.

However I need to get this website up pretty fast so I've opted for the simple Wordpress option (because its all already there!)

I've done customisation work with Wordpress before but I've got no idea how to customise it on this scale!

So basically I need pages like 'Media', 'mailing list', 'tour', 'merch', 'contact', etc.

I'm not asking how to do this, I'm asking if anybody knows of any plug-ins or any simple ways to implement them!

Like the mailing list. Would I have to add columns into the data base and add all the logic code myself? if so where in the hell does this logic code go in the huge framework?

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Thankyou
x

Comment: You should probably research before asking: http://google.com/search?q=wordpress+plugins+for+bands most WP plugins are very easy to install and use, also checkout http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Learn about designing wordpress theme and then plugins. if you want pre-made plugins then find here. [Wordpress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins)

Comment: YOu could google for a plugin or a theme and spend the time finding nothing that fits your need. or you can just google on how to make your own theme. It profits, just an opinion

Comment: For tourdates i would say gigpress http://gigpress.com/download/. Contact form would be the classic wp-forms http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/. Everything else depends on what you need. Either write a plugin or find one that is up to date with latest wordpress version and is being maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=mailinglist

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=gallery&sort=

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=calendar&sort=

http://www.google.com/

Comment: Well I get the idea but I was looking for more informative answers -.- I know how to google

Comment: then please ask a more specific question :)